# How to make a hotkey trigger one time while it is held down?

Tags: autohotkey, hotkeys

The problem with my code is that it triggers it unlimited times when being held down, I only want it to trigger one time. I want the hotkey to be triggered **when "q" is pushed down**

```
q::
If(GetKeyState("q", "P") = 1)
    Send {Space}{Space}
return
```

I know some keys have a Up or Down keyword, but I do not know about "q"
I do not know how to execute the hotkey only one time

Comment: https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/94157-hold-down-key-execute-once/